# How to make this Python code run with VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, api, python-requests

I don't have any experience with VBA so I'm struggling a bit.

So I have this Python code that makes an API authentication and then transforms a JSON from the API call into an excel file and saves it.

```
Sub RunPythonScriptQuery()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExePath As String, PythonScriptPath As String
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    
    PythonExePath = """C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"""
    PythonScriptPath = """C:\Users\me\vbatest\parse.py"""
    
    objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath
    
    MsgBox ("File parsed!")
    
End Sub
```

What I want to do is to click on a button on excel and execute this whole operation. Even though I'm not getting any errors, It's not saving the file as I need. Do you have any clue on how I solve this issue with VBA ?

Comment: Try `objShell.Run PythonExePath & " " & PythonScriptPath`

Comment: It remains the same thing. It seems like the Python script is doing nothing.

Comment: And if you open a CMD window and attempt to run `"C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "C:\Users\me\vbatest\parse.py"` - does it work?

Comment: It does not. It's giving me python: can't open parse.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

in Excel VBA -

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbRunPythonScriptHello()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExePath As String
Dim PythonScriptPath As String
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    PythonExePath = """C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"""
    PythonScriptPath = """C:\Users\david\Desktop\py_HelloWorld.py"""
    objShell.Run PythonExePath & PythonScriptPath
    MsgBox ("Hello World Python from VBA")
End Sub
```

and here is the Python code that the VBA calls -

from - digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-wait-time-wait-for-input

```
import time
sec = input('Let us wait for user input. Let me know how many seconds to sleep now.\n')
print('Going to sleep for', sec, 'seconds.')
time.sleep(int(sec))
print('Enough of sleeping, I quit!')
time.sleep(int(sec))
```

This is using Windows 11 -

*Edition        Windows 11 Home
Version     22H2
Installed on    ‎20/‎01/‎2023
OS build        22621.1413*

and Excel -

*Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2303 Build 16.0.16227.20202) 64-bit*

with Python -

*Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32*

Comment: I tried exactly the same but changed paths. It only returns the msgbox but it does nothing else.

Comment: @CED try to run the Python code without Excel VBA maybe you will see the error message.

Comment: It works perfectly when I run it on my notebook.

Comment: I did it by running:

C:\Users\me>where python
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

Comment: Still not working here, basically nothing happens.
Is it possible to execute this entire operation I'm trying to do with Python by just using VBA ?