# How to successfully execute Python through VBA

Tags: python, pandas, excel, vba

This is the VBA code I'm trying to run:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RunPythonScript()

'Declare Variables
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String

'Create a new Object shell.
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

PythonExe = """C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe """
PythonScript = """C:\Users\me\test\VBAult\auth.py"""

'Run the Python Script
objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript, 0, True

MsgBox "Executed!"

End Sub
```

This is my Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import requests
import json

url_auth = 'https://api-gateway.com/uaa/oauth/token'

payload_auth = {'grant_type': 'client'} 

username = "username"
password = "password"
  
response_auth = requests.post(url_auth, auth=(username, password), data=payload_auth)
 
data = response_auth.json()

url_f = 'https://api-gateway.com/api/test'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ data['access_token'],
}

payload_f = json.dumps([
  {
    "operation": "xxxxx",
    "reference": "xxxxx",
    "status": "xxx"
  }
])

response_f = requests.get(url_f, headers=headers, data=payload_f, verify=True)

json_data = json.loads(response_f.text)

df_json_data = pd.json_normalize(json_data)

df_json_data.to_excel('C:\Users\me\Downloads\convertjson.xlsx', index=False)
```

It makes some API calls and converts the JSON response into an Excel file at the end.
It works perfectly when I execute it from my notebook, but it does nothing when I execute it from VBA using the code above. Only returning the msgbox, but not creating the excel file I need.

How can I archive what I need by making VBA and my python script work together ?

Comment: Does this question differs from the one you asked yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985678/how-to-make-this-python-code-run-with-vba?  You still will need to have a space between `PythonExe` and `PythonScript`.

Comment: `df_final.to_excel` ?? The data frame from json is `df_json_data`

Comment: Oops, I fixed it!

Comment: See this answer from yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985678/how-to-make-this-python-code-run-with-vba/75988925#75988925

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me. The following code will print output/error on the VBA console, allowing you to determine the actual problem.

```
Sub python_script_run()

    pyexe = "C:\thonny\python.exe" 'change to your python executable
    pysc = "D:\_code_\SEM_RENO_V3\sem_reno.py" 'change python script path as required
    
    pth = Left(pysc, InStrRev(pysc, "\") - 1)
    ChDir pth 'chage directory to script
    
    sCmd = pyexe & " " & pysc
    Debug.Print sCmd
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set ObjExec = objShell.Exec("cmd.exe /k " & sCmd)
    
    Do
        strFromProc = ObjExec.Stdout.ReadLine()
        Debug.Print strFromProc 'error/output will be printed in vba console
    Loop While Not ObjExec.Stdout.atEndOfStream

End Sub
```